# Hide DataGrid row with specific Value C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, hide

I have an xml file with  and they got an Attribute "Active = true". If i delete a Customer, it sets "active" to false, but the customer should still be in my xml file. I simply want to hide the DataGrid Column where the row "active" is false. So every customer with "active = false" should not be displayed in my Data Grid. I hope you understand what im trying to do :P

I thought about something like this:

```
private void HideCustomer()
        {
            if (active == false)
            {
                DataGrid.HideRow ???? // So if the customer has this attribute set to "false" the row 
            }                         // should be hidden in the DataGrid
        }
```

Comment: "I have an xml file". Are you using an xmldataprovider or are you translating the data to objects?

Comment: i have textboxes, where i can input a name and a surname for example, and when i hit the save key, i write the xml file with the xmlserializer. my datagrid itemssource is my list of customers. I hope that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an `RowStyle` with a `DataTrigger` in the XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

This requires that `IsActive` is a *public property*. You should also implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) to raise change notifications.